# insert Associative array into data base

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i am try to insert Associative array in database which recieve it from ajax file . and
when print it in console  it be like   **{name: "name", number: "5"}** .

```
$services_array = explode(',' ,$_REQUEST['services_array'] );
foreach ($services_array as $name => $quantity ) {
     $add_data   = $engine->connect()->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `requests` SET 
        `section` = '$name',
        `quantity` = '$quantity '
        ");
}
```

the problem is in database the field of *section* the data in it be 0 or 1 or 2
and in field of *quantity* the data in it be [object Object]

Comment: `'$quantity '` I'd remove that space

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `$_REQUEST['services_array'] == '{name: "name", number: "5"}'`, yes?

Comment: Dump `$_REQUEST['services_array']`. Stating what the console prints still tells nothing of the way PHP will receive this. That would depend on the settings of your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

looks for me that you just iterating over the rows, so your $name is your row index and your $quantity is the true object with contains the keys that you expecting, try to echo the $quantity object using:

```
var_dump($quantity);
```

Comment: the output is [object Object]

Comment: can you show more from your service, what do you send from your service ?